# ¿Cómo utilizar una SweetAlert dentro de un submit?

Tags: sweetalert, submit

estoy intentando que al presionar un botón tipo submit me aparezca una alerta de confirmación. Pero esta misma desaparece rápidamente, sin la posibilidad de quedar fija y no poder dar el botón de OK.

Adjunto mi código:

Función SweetAlert

```
 function mostrarAlerta() {
        swal({
            title: "Actualización Exitosa",
            text: "Procesamiento de datos realizado correctamente",
            icon: "success"
        })
 }
```

Mi botón tipo submit, aclaro que no puedo pasarlo a button porque mi funcionalidad dentro de ese botón no sería ejecutada.

```
<input type="submit" onclick="mostrarAlerta()" value="Procesar Datos" class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="/File/CargarSQLServer" />
```

¿Que podría cambiar en mi función?, de manera que la alerta se mantenga hasta el momento que yo presione OK manteniendo el submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>    
 <input type="submit" onclick="mostrarAlerta()" id="input" value="Procesar Datos" class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="/File/CargarSQLServer" />   


 <script>
    function mostrarAlerta() {
                 var cod = document.getElementById("input").value;
            if (cod != "") {  //COMPRUEBA CAMPOS VACIOS
                Swal.fire({
                  icon: 'error',
                  title: 'Oops...',
                  text: 'Los campos no puedes quedar vacios',
                     });
                return false;
            };
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Me parece que no me explique bien, en este botón submit hago una carga a una base de datos. Únicamente ocupo una alerta que sea visible al yo presionar el submit, sin necesidad de una validación. Como mostre al inicio, esta es visible pero desaparece rápidamente.